# I'm Having trouble adding values to a ArrayList with methods

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, methods, parameters

So basically my problem is in this program which i will explain better after i put it in

```
    package learning;
//This class has an important method that i have been working on called Dice6 don't delete

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameBoard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome To The Gameboard");
        System.out.println("What is your name player 1?");

        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String ScanResult1 = Scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Well... " + ScanResult1 + " This is the Board");

        System.out.println("~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~|");// Don't Question its
                                                        // placement its weird,
                                                        // but it works
        System.out.println("               |");
        System.out.println("               |~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~");

        System.out.println("Lets start with a Dice Roll");

        System.out.println(ScanResult1 + " Got a Roll of " + Dice6(10));

        Scan.close();

    }

    static int Dice6(int y) {
        ArrayList<Integer> Dice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Dice.add(1);
        Dice.add(2);
        Dice.add(3);
        Dice.add(4);
        Dice.add(5);
        Dice.add(6);


        int DiceAmount = Dice.size();
        while (DiceAmount != 6) {
            DiceAmount= DiceAmount - 1;
            Dice.add(Dice.size() + 1);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Dice);
        Collections.shuffle(Dice);
        Integer DiceResult = Dice.get(3);
        return DiceResult;
    }

}
```

Ok so the problem I'm having is from 
    System.out.println(ScanResult1 + " Got a Roll of " + Dice6(10));
to the bottom of the program basically I'm trying to add Array values in the ArrayList by using the parameter 10.... what suppose to happen is there is suppose to be 10 values in the ArrayList depending on what i put in the parameter....I've tried a lot of things and done a lot of fixing, i ever did a for(blank x : Dice) to show all values and 10 didn't come up only the original 6....if any body has any idea how to solve this please tell me

Comment: I'm not following you.  What makes you think that your code should put 10 elements into your `List`?

Comment: Also, your code would be easier for others to read if you followed standard naming conventions.  In particular, method and local variable names should start with a lowercase letter be in camelCase.

Comment: What does it mean that " there is suppose to be 10 values in the ArrayList depending on what i put in the parameter"?  I suppose you're talking about method `Dice6()`, but if there are supposed to be exactly 10 values then what does the parameter have to do with it?  Or do you mean that the parameter is supposed to specify how many values there are?

Comment: Also, have you considered that your `Dice6()` method is a truly horrible implementation of generating a random number?  I suggest you look at class `Random` for a far more direct way.

Comment: @John Bollinger you are correct. Coding standards are very bad.. I initially thought Dice6(10) is a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes no sense:

```
int DiceAmount = Dice.size();       /* this will be 6 */
while (DiceAmount != 6) {           /* this will never be true, do you want y here? */
    DiceAmount= DiceAmount - 1;     /* huh? I think you want addition here */
    Dice.add(Dice.size() + 1);      /* this will never happen */
}
```

More in "answer form"... Use this:

```
int DiceAmount = Dice.size();
while (DiceAmount != y) 
    DiceAmount= DiceAmount + 1;
    Dice.add(Dice.size() + 1);
}
```

Comment: You are quite right, but this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you for helping i was very confused and didn't realize that the while command wasn't running i got mixed up because i forgot the the dice amount will always be 6.... yes i did mean to put y because my plan was to have for example it to keep making a dice.add until it was subtracted enough to = 6